# anova and model residuals in LMER

Tags: anova, lme4-nlme, multilevel-analysis, residuals

I am sufficiently educated in R and linear regression to make dangerous unknowing/overconfident mistakes due to inexperience, so want to make sure that I am not making those mistakes.

I have dependent variable CA (normally distributed), and two categorical factors, C and W.  Predictors that vary with C are C1, C2, and C3.  Predictors that vary with W are W1 and W2.  There are 200K samples, and W is quite large (a few thousand) and about 30 C levels.  Originally I wanted to fit an ambitious model with random intercepts for both word and community and random slopes for the interaction C1*C2*C3 and W1*W2, but the model ran into computational problems in lme4.

So what I did was I fit the following simpler model:

`lmer(CA ~ (1|C) + C1*C2*C3 + W1*W2)`

Then I tested nested models by systematically eliminating predictors, did a multi-way ANOVA, and selected the most complex model where the ChiSq test p-value was under 0.05.  This happens to be `CA ~ (1|C) + W1*W2`.

However, the residuals (call it CA.res) are still normally distributed.  So I took CA.res and ran another LMER, this time with W random intercepts.

`lmer(CA.res ~ (1|W) + C1*C2*C3)`

Then via a multi-way ANOVA we find that C2 can be eliminated from the model. There are still normally distributed residuals with a smaller variance.

So what I understand this to be is a hierarchical model in which fixed effects C1 and C3 have an interaction given W intercepts based on the residuals of W1, W2, and W3 having an interaction given C intercepts.

My questions is: is the use of the residuals of CA statistically legitimate or a fallacious way to squeeze value from C and W?

Thanks.

Comment: Please can you provide more information about these data ? What exactly are these variables and how were they measured ? And why are you fitting a model on the residuals of the prevuous model ?